# MYSQL stored procedure running really slowly (connection times out)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
BEGIN

declare currID INT(30);
declare maxID INT(30);
declare first_period datetime;
declare s_date datetime;
declare tot_sent INT(30);
declare weighted_score FLOAT(30);
declare aid INT(10);

set first_period = date_add(stats_start_from, INTERVAL 49 DAY);
set currID = (select min(rowid) from weekly_stats);
set maxID = (select max(rowid) from weekly_stats);

WHILE (currID <= 40000) DO

select accountid, week_start_date INTO aid, s_date from weekly_stats where rowid = currID;

if (s_date >= first_period) then

set tot_sent = (select sum(weekly_total_sent) from weekly_stats where (accountid = aid AND week_start_date <= s_date AND week_start_date >= (date_add(s_date, INTERVAL (-49) DAY)))); 
set weighted_score = (select sum(weekly_total_sent*weekly_raw_score) from weekly_stats where (accountid = aid AND week_start_date <= s_date AND week_start_date >= (date_add(s_date, INTERVAL (-49) DAY))));
set weighted_score = weighted_score/tot_sent;

update weekly_stats set weighted_scores = weighted_score where rowid =   currID;

end if;

set currID = currID + 1;

end while;

END
```

Basically, I have a column in the table called weighted_scores that calculates as follows: weighted score = sum of (raw score*sent mail) for the last 8 weeks, divided by the total mail sent in the last 8 weeks. So, it is a 8 week score average weighted by the volume of mail sent each week.

My procedure runs really slowly and times out (after ten minutes) for even a small number of rows. I was wondering what the issue was, maybe inefficient querying, calculations, etc? Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
create table weekly_stats
(
    accountid INT(10),
    week_start_date datetime,
    weekly_total_sent INT(30),
    weekly_hbounce INT(30),
    weekly_sbounce INT(30),
    weekly_spam INT(30),
    weekly_optouts INT(30),
    weekly_opens INT(30),
    weekly_CT INT(30),
    rowid INT(30),
    weekly_raw_score FLOAT(30),
    weighted_scoresFLOAT(30)

    -- indexes not shown
);
```

Comment: you really should reconfigure that. why run a single-row select, then check `if (s_date >= ..)`? Why can't you do that with a `where` clause to begin with?  and why run that as a single query in a loop anyways? why not run select everything you  need in a SINGLE query, then loop on the results?

Comment: Create indexes on columns to improve querying speed accountid , week_start_date Or you can use mysql partitioning if you have huge amount of data to improve the query performances.

Comment: You need to decided which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sqlserver. This looks horribly inefficient in any DBMS though because you keep selecting columns from the same table in subsequent queries. Most likely these all be simplified into a single select statement instead of multiples inside a loop.

Comment: why are you doing while currID<=40000? do you keep modifying your sp all the time?

Comment: what would be very helpful would be output from `show create table weekly_stats`